# Insert each word of string into vector and calculating occurrence of each word

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I am trying to insert words of string into vector and then getting it's occurrence. 
I have done significant work here. **Problem is inplace of calculating word below code count each character occurrence.**

Probably I am inserting characters into vector rather word. I tried to get solution from google but not getting what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

std::pair < int, std::string > mytransform(const std::pair < std::string, int >p)
{
    return std::pair < int, std::string > (p.second, p.first);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string result_string=argv[1];
    std::istringstream iss;
    std::multimap < int, std::string, std::greater < int >>dst;
    std::multimap < int, std::string >::iterator rec;
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string,int> occurrences;
    occurrences s1;
    std::vector<std::string> most;
    std::map < std::string, int >src;

    std::vector<std::string> writable(result_string.size() + 1);
    std::copy(result_string.begin(), result_string.end(), writable.begin());

    for (std::vector < std::string >::iterator it = writable.begin(); it != writable.end(); it++)
    ++src[*it];

    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), mytransform);
    std::multimap < int, std::string >::iterator it = dst.begin();

   for (it = dst.begin(); it != dst.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->second << ":" << it->first << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
technoworld@ubuntu:~/Videos/LinSocket/Modular$ ./q "one one two"
o:3
 :2
e:2
n:2
t:1
w:1
:1
```

Rather it should be:

```
technoworld@ubuntu:~/Videos/LinSocket/Modular$ ./q "one one two"
one:2
two:1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string input =  "one one two";
    std::istringstream in(input);
    std::map<std::string, unsigned> counter;
    std::string s;
    while(in >> s) {
        ++counter[s];
    }
    for(const auto& kv: counter) {
        std::cout << kv.first << ": " << kv.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using iterator for the string, so you iterate through the characters. instead, do a split to the string and iterate the strings in the result

```
std::string word;

while( getline(writable, word, ' ') )
{
   ++src[word];
}
```

for more information read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: I was thinking I am doing something what you told. But I dont figure out how to do it!

Comment: @Karimkhan i've edit the answer, it might not be fully accurate, but it is hard to understand your code

Answer (score 1):

You're simply pushing characters into your `writable` vector
and many unnecessary stuffs

If you're trying to give it as a single string use :

```
std::vector<std::string> writable ;

std::stringstream ss(result_string);
std::string item;
while (std::getline(ss, item, ' ')) {
    writable.push_back(item);
}


for (std::vector < std::string >::iterator it = writable.begin();
       it != writable.end(); it++)
 ++src[*it];
```

Or why not simply : (this won't require to quote your command line argument)

```
    for(int i=0;i<argc;++i)
     ++src[std::string(argv[i])];
     std::multimap < std::string,int >::iterator it ;

   for (it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
     std::cout << it->second << ":" << it->first << std::endl;
```

Comment: thanks, can you please explain : `while (std::getline(ss, item, ' '))`

Comment: @Karimkhan [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads character from input stream here `stringstream` and puts them into a string. The third argument signifies the delimiter character, using which you want to separate your inputs, here a space